# Extract matching substrings from a list to new list in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
garbage
moregarbaged89849843
MDeduri09ri44830
Some short sentence
Whatever ... key: d11001bfa937eee2f84f55a11b207356 (KID=01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf)
Whatever2 ... key: a0ee2d0f8272355f750c5434db85291a (KID=0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3)
Whatever3 ... key: fe216ba17e5af807ce5af8e43cf3c031 (KID=0102900a2bc54111833631ea7bb855ed)
77EB0A2C7C42EDC27A3D26E72A02BB29:01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf status 'garbage'
blah blah:0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3 has status 'usable'
77EB0A2C7C42EDC27A3D26E72A02BB29:blah blah
```

I only care about the key and KID parts, and want to extract them to separate lists

My regex for that is `key: (\w|\d){30,}` and `KID=(\w|\d){30,}` respectively.

Code I'm using is

```
matchkid = re.compile('KID=(\w|\d){30,}')
matchkey = re.compile('key: (\w|\d){30,}')

filteredkids = [a for a in lis if matchkid.search(a)]
filteredkeys = [b for b in lis if matchkey.search(b)]

print(filteredkids)
print('\n')
print(filteredkeys)
```

Where `lis` is a list made from the lines of the text document

The output is

```
['Whatever ... key: d11001bfa937eee2f84f55a11b207356 (KID=01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf)', 'Whatever2 ... key: a0ee2d0f8272355f750c5434db85291a (KID=0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3)', 'Whatever3 ... key: fe216ba17e5af807ce5af8e43cf3c031 (KID=0102900a2bc54111833631ea7bb855ed)']


['Whatever ... key: d11001bfa937eee2f84f55a11b207356 (KID=01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf)', 'Whatever2 ... key: a0ee2d0f8272355f750c5434db85291a (KID=0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3)', 'Whatever3 ... key: fe216ba17e5af807ce5af8e43cf3c031 (KID=0102900a2bc54111833631ea7bb855ed)']
```

Which is wrong, the desired output is

```
['KID=01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf', 'KID=0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3', 'KID=0102900a2bc54111833631ea7bb855ed']

['key: d11001bfa937eee2f84f55a11b207356', 'key: a0ee2d0f8272355f750c5434db85291a', 'key: fe216ba17e5af807ce5af8e43cf3c031']
```

I have tried tweaking my regex and looking at other similar questions, but nothing seems to work and most of the time I just get empty lists.

Hoping to find some guidance here, thanks in advance

Comment: Do not use `(\w|\d)`, use `\w`. `\w` matches digits. And then just use `re.findall`, `re.findall(r''KID=\w{30,}", text)` and `re.findall(r''key: \w{30,}", text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(\w|\d){30,}` is not a good pattern as it creates a repeated capturing group, and is redundant itself: `\w` matches digits, too, so `\w{30,}` is enough.

Next, you are using `re.search` that only returns a Match data object, and you use listeneing comprehension to iterate over that object, while you need to grab all matches from your strings.

You can fix the code by using

```py
filteredkids = re.findall(r'KID=\w{30,}', text)
filteredkeys = re.findall(r'key: \w{30,}', text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lEJr0I):

```py
import re
text = """garbage
moregarbaged89849843
MDeduri09ri44830
Some short sentence
Whatever ... key: d11001bfa937eee2f84f55a11b207356 (KID=01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf)
Whatever2 ... key: a0ee2d0f8272355f750c5434db85291a (KID=0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3)
Whatever3 ... key: fe216ba17e5af807ce5af8e43cf3c031 (KID=0102900a2bc54111833631ea7bb855ed)
77EB0A2C7C42EDC27A3D26E72A02BB29:01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf status 'garbage'
blah blah:0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3 has status 'usable'
77EB0A2C7C42EDC27A3D26E72A02BB29:blah blah"""
filteredkids = re.findall(r'KID=\w{30,}', text)
filteredkeys = re.findall(r'key: \w{30,}', text)
print( filteredkids )
print( filteredkeys )
```

Output:

```py
['KID=01002d737832455680cffbadf1092baf', 'KID=0101bfa0ab9641a0b863ef76519a48d3', 'KID=0102900a2bc54111833631ea7bb855ed']
['key: d11001bfa937eee2f84f55a11b207356', 'key: a0ee2d0f8272355f750c5434db85291a', 'key: fe216ba17e5af807ce5af8e43cf3c031']
```